# How to use multiple message decorators on NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Pretty straight forward question:
I have `methodOne` and `methodTwo` on my controller, if I place `MessagePattern` decorator above one of them, everything works as it should when it receives a message, but when I place it above another method (so I now have two methods using that decorator) it will only reach the first method.

Is it possible to use multiple?

Comment: I believe that you just can do things easily as using 1 decorator for 1 method and in that method, call 2 others. Seems like the @MessagePattern will just match once

Comment: @MessagePattern with same pattern on two methods? won't make sense.
if you want to do two things with a single message, either call two methods from controller method or just add two events with different patterns from your publisher itself.